# Using whenLoaded in Resource Collection I got error

Tags: laravel, resources

In laravel 6 app I have a Resource Collection, which works ok for me :

```
class UserSkillCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public static $wrap = 'user_skills';

    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return $this->collection->transform(function($userSkill){
            return [
                'id' => $userSkill->id,
                'user_id' => $userSkill->user_id,
                'user_name' => $userSkill->user_name,
                'skill_id' => $userSkill->skill_id,
                'skill_name' => $userSkill->skill_name,
                'rating' => $userSkill->rating,
                'created_at' => $userSkill->created_at,
            ];
        });

    }
```

except when some fields are defined, like user_name, I have keys with null values.

To get rid of them I tried to use whenLoaded, but with line :

```
'user_id' => $this->whenLoaded('user_id'),
```

I got error :

```
"message": "Method Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::relationLoaded does not exist.",
```

Which way is valid ?

**MODIFIED :** 
I added relations in models and making :

```
  'user' => $userSkill->whenLoaded('user'),
```

or

```
  'user' => $this->whenLoaded('user'),
```

I got error :

```
Call to undefined method App\UserSkill::whenLoaded(
```

I suppose this error as I call it from Collection.
How correctly ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`relationLoaded()` is a method inherited from the `HasRelationships` trait on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

Your code is trying to access it on a instance of an `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.

Try accessing the relationship `user` rather than it's key `user_id`. Like so:

```
$this->whenLoaded('user')
```

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED